# Pandas - group by the entire MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Suppose I have a dataframe indexed by a MultiIndex with 4 levels, and I want to group by the index.

I know I can do

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1,2,3])...
```

But, is there a syntactically better way, so that I don't need to know the size of the MultiIndex in order?

Something like

```
df.groupby(axis=0)...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.groupby(level=range(len(df.index.levels)))
```

Not necessarily pretty, but it's generalized.